# Convert Curl to Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: json, powershell, curl, post, invoke-restmethod

## Problem

I am having a hard time converting a **curl** call into a Powershell **Invoke-RestMethod** call as Powershell doesn't really thow the most informative error messages (if any).

## Curl call (Ubuntu)

```
token = "djsakldsakldjaslda"
host = "https://lalala.azuredatabricks.net/"
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(token)" $(host)/api/2.0/clusters/create -d $(cat my_file.json)
```

## Invoke-RestMethod call (Powershell)

```
$token= "djsakldsakldjaslda"
$host = "https://lalala.azuredatabricks.net/"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $host/api/2.0/clusters/create -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer " + $token} -Body $(get-content my_file.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

I have various formats for the body, but no matter what I send, I just get some HTML back for a login page. On Ubuntu with Curl everything works perfectly.

NOTE:
The problem seemed to be that PowerShell cannot handle double-"/" as in "https://lalala.azuredatabricks.net//api/2.0/clusters/create".

The strange part is that **Invoke-RestMethod** gets to the login page, but fails from there.

Comment: Try to add `ConvertTo-Json` after `ConvertFrom-Json` =  $(get-content my_file.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json)

Comment: Lol, that seems to work. OMG, why do I need to use this terrible tool :P

Comment: I found the error, it seems that unlike Curl the PowerShell method does not accept "//" as in https://lalala.azuredatabricks.net//api/2.0/clusters/create.... Strange that it makes no errors then, but indeed reaches the site...

Comment: see my answer for an explanation, you can also try to remove both ` | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json` maybe it will work. check it :)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Huh? When the file already is JSON, and the OP calls `ConvertFrom-JSON`, but the API expects JSON, then the solution is not calling `ConvertTo-JSON` again, the solution is dropping the `ConvertFrom-JSON`.

Comment: I thought about it but from my experience not always is works, lol. id it worked for you? sometimes the `ConvertTo-Json` create a better format than in the original file

Comment: JSON is JSON, the way it is formatted makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body is expected to be JSON format, when you take the file and add the `| ConvertFrom-Json` the content becomes a PowerShell object.

So, you can remove the `| ConvertFrom-Json` and it should work :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up not using ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json, as the real problem was the extra "/" in the URL. If you type that into you answer, I will accept :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `-InFile` to upload a file. Don't forget to set the content type.

Wrapped for legibility (escaping the EOL works as line continuation in PowerShell, it looks funny because StackOverflow syntax highlighting cannot handle it):

```
Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method Post `
    -Uri "$host/api/2.0/clusters/create"
    -Headers @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $token"
    } `
    -Infile my_file.json
    -ContentType "application/json"
```